# wp-content/db.php : where is this file?

Tags: wpdb

At the top of the source file `wp-includes/wp-db.php` I can find the following comment:

```
/**
 * WordPress Database Access Abstraction Object
 *
 * It is possible to replace this class with your own
 * by setting the $wpdb global variable in wp-content/db.php
 * file to your class. The wpdb class will still be included,
 * so you can extend it or simply use your own.
```

I was wondering how replacing the wpdb class with a different class
would work but I cannot find any file under wp-content/db.php. Is
there an error in the documentation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would create your own `dp.php` file in the `wp-content` directory; if you define `$wpdb` in there, it will replace WordPress's default `$wpdb` object.

It's not listed on the [Pluggable Functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions) list (not a big surprise, as `$wpdb` is a class, not a function), but it seems similar in concept.

Also, if you haven't read it yet, I'd recommend you peruse the [WPDB Class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class) documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create the file by yourself. This is one of the files that are reffered as "drop-ins". They are not distributed with the wordpress core and their purpose is to extend functionality, in the db.php case to replace the default database "driver" with another one, for example to communicate with a DB which is not MYSQL.

A typical structure of the files is

```
class altdb extends wpdb{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct( DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
    }

    function insert($table, $data, $format = null) {
        // code to override insert
    }

    function query($sql) {
        // code to override query
    }
}

global $wpdb;
$wpdb = new altdb();
```

That is a relatively simple example that only overides insert and query but still uses the same DB. You can go much more complex then that.