# How to get all queries's results after they have executed?

Tags: plugin-development, filters, hooks, mysql, actions

I need to get query results after they have executed

```
    add_filter('query', 'query_recorder_wrapper_wptc');
```

I use `query` filter to get all queries before they executed, I also want after they executed. I exhausted of searching this.

Is there any `hooks` or script for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

### Extending the `wpdb` class

We can create the `db.php` file under `wp-content/` directory to override the `wpdb` class to our needs.

I checked this site for such examples and found one by @MarkKaplun [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/160819/26350).

Here's an example how one can get access to the *last result*, after each query has run:

```
<?php
/**
 * db.php - Override the global $wpdb object to collect all query results
 */
namespace WPSE\Question242685;

class DB extends \wpdb
{
    public function __construct( $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname, $dbhost )
    {
        // Parent constructor
        parent::__construct( $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname, $dbhost );
    }

    public function query( $query )
    {
        // Parent query
        $val = parent::query( $query );

        //----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Edit this to your needs
        //
        // Warning: It can be slow and resource demanding to collect all results 
        if ( defined( 'SAVEQUERIES' ) && SAVEQUERIES )
        {
            // do something with $this->last_result;
        }
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------

        return $val;
    }

} // end class

// Override the global wpdb object
$GLOBALS['wpdb'] = new DB( DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST );
```

Here we assume the `SAVEQUERIES` is defined as `true` in the `wp-config.php` file.

**Note** that collecting *all* the results can be *resource demanding*, so you better only test this on a dev install.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use the `wp` action with the global variable `$wp_query`, like so:

```
function all_queried_items(){

    global $wp_query;

    $all_queried_posts = $wp_query->posts;

}

add_action('wp', 'all_queried_items');
```