# Track write actions to the database

Tags: wp-query, filters, database, actions

Is there a single action or filter that is run when a

- post is updated
- option is updated
- user is updated
- plugin is updated
- any other content is updated and wrote to the database

?

I want to be able to track all the changes I made in my development environment and save them to a file so that I can then update my live database with these patches automatically.

Is this maybe the filter I'm looking for?: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/query/
or does anyone know of a hook that's better suited?

Or is there a plugin out there, that I haven't found yet, that does exactly this?

Comment: There is a `query` filter in wpdb query https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/query/ that appears to run with all sql requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there's a plugin out there that does quite this!

It's [VersionPress](https://versionpress.net)!

In [this blog post](https://blog.versionpress.net/2015/10/the-db-php-issue/) is explained what they used to track all the complicated changes.

Instead of using the 'query' filter they use the option to create a db.php file in the wp-contents directory to extend $wpdb like explained in this post: [wp-content/db.php : where is this file?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/160813/wp-content-db-php-where-is-this-file)